# connecting to Microsoft SQL Server using sqlalchemy '1.4.22', python 3.9

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have an extremely simple setup. Microsoft SQL Server 64b (version 15), installed on Windows 10. TP Port on TCP/IP properties is blank (Don't understand why is it so tough to figure out what port is it running on).

I am able to connect to my database using SQL Management Studio with:

> Server name: DEVSERVER\MSSQLDEV2019

and both "Windows Authentication" as well as "SQL Server Authentication".

However, when I try using sqlalchemy or MySQLdb, I cant seem to connect, generally getting two types of error:

```
DATABASECONFIG = {
    'DEV': {
        'server': 'MSSQLDEV2019',
        'database': 'family',
        'username': 'famrwuser',
        'password': 'password'
    }
}

class SQLDBConnection(object):

    def __init__(self, configname):
        config = DATABASECONFIG[configname]
        self.server = config['server']
        self.database = config['database']
        self.username = config['username']
        self.password = config['password']
    def _connstring(self):
        connstring = 'mysql://%s:%s@%s/%s'%(
            self.username, self.password,  self.server, self.database)
        return connstring
    def engine(self):
        engine = create_engine(self._connstring(), echo=True)
        return engine

    def getrawresultset(self, sql):
        with self.engine().connect() as connection:
            results = connection.execute(sql)
        return results

x = SQLDBConnection('DEV')
x.engine()
print(x.getrawresultset('select % from dbo.members'))
```

with 'server': 'DEVSERVER\MSSQLDEV2019' also, I get the error

```
"Unknown MySQL server host 'MSSQLDEV2019'
```

I also tried 'server': 'localhost', I get the error

```
"Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'
```

I did try using MySQLdb, with all versions of host, without any success

```
import MySQLdb
Con = MySQLdb.Connect(host="DEVSERVER\MSSQLDEV2019", user="famrwuser", passwd="password", db="family")
Cursor = Con.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.members"
Cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: MySQLdb is for MySQL. Try instead `pyodbc` or something specifically for SQL Server.

Comment: @mechanical_meat - Thanks. Your suggestion sort of helped.  I was able to make it work with pyodbc. However, I am more inclined to make sqlalchemy work. Tried using mssql+pyodbc. Didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

So, finally this worked:

```
conntring = "mssql+pyodbc://famrwuser:password@DEVSERVER\MSSQLDEV2019:49764/family?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
```

The key was (1) port number - not sure how/when/why I changed that port number (yeah, curse at me) and (2) ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server - the + was the key instead of spaces